# General definition of POVM

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, quantum-mechanics

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) gives the following definition of *positive operator-valued measure* (POVM):

> A POVM on a measurable space $(X,M)$ is a function $F$ defined on $M$ whose values are bounded non-negative self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ such that $F(X) = 1_\mathcal{H}$ and for every $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$ the map $E \mapsto \langle F(E) \psi , \psi \rangle$ is a non-negative countably additive measure on $M$.

When the set of outcomes $X$ is finite and/or the Hilbert space has finite dimension, a simpler definition can be easily found in standard textbooks, but in the general case none of the books I've checked (on quantum mechanics, functional analysis or $C^*$-algebras) contains a definition. Do you have a reference, other than Wikipedia, for an equivalent definition of POVM?

Comment: Are you looking for a source of the definition you cited, or an equivalent, but different definition?

Comment: @MaoWao either. I’m looking for a source with Wikipedia’s definition or a different definition as long as it is general enough, without assuming the Hilbert space is finite dimensional or the set of outcomes is finite or countable.

Answer (score 1):

One possible source is "[Notes on Spectral Theory](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/09/09-32.pdf)" by Berberian. He defines POVMs in Definition 1. Note that strictly speaking, his definition is not equivalent to Wikipedia's definition since he only assumes the measure to be defined on a ring of subsets instead of a $\sigma$-algebra and he does not require the normalization $F(X)=1_{\mathcal H}$. But if the domain happens to be a $\sigma$-algebra and $F(X)=1_{\mathcal H}$, both definitions coincide (see Theorem 1).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two books which feature a definition of POVMs as general as what you are looking for that immediately came to mind:

- *"Quantum Theory of Open Systems"* (1976) by Davies: he introduces POVMs in Chapter 4, Definition 1.1 (although he called it "PMV")
- *"The Mathematical Language of Quantum Theory"* (2012) by Heinosaari & Ziman: see Definition 3.5 therein